Why CMake does not add library to RPATH?
Question
Hi! I've observed a behavior of CMake which confuses me and which I would like to control. CMake seems to reject/remove/not include certain dependencies from RPATH: libraries from Nix store are all included in RPATH but a libraries present in /home/user/xyz is not. I would like that last libraries to be also used in RPATH.
Full description
I have a C++ package P which I build inside Nix. I enter the Nix shell (nix develop) and proceed to build the project by calling mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make -j. The whole project builds and I can run test executables from within the build tree, without the need to install.
Now I make an alteration: I want to "inject" one of the Nix-level dependencies, D, by manipulating environment variables set by Nix and utilized by CMake.
Specifically, I first build that dependency the same way as described above, and at the end I install it to a local directory: cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/xyz && make -j && cmake --install . --prefix /home/user/xyz. Now, I enter my main package P and I edit the following environment variables: CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH, CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH, CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, NIX_LDFLAGS, NIX_CFLAGS_COMPILE, propagatedBuildInputs. In each variable, I replace each occurrence of path pointing to D in Nix store with my local path /home/user/xyz.
Now, I proceed to build P in the usual way. At some point in the build process, I see a linker error: linker cannot find the library provided by D. The fix is to configure P with -DCMAKE_BUILD_RPATH=/home/user/xyz. Now I can build and link all components of P.

None of the variables noted in your question post affects on RPATH settings. Probably, RPATH is not related to your problem at all. Please, provide [mcve]: code, which reproduces the problem, and the exact error message.

Apologies, my mistake. I meant to say that the fix is to "configure P with -DCMAKE_BUILD_RPATH=..." - I edited my question to reference the correct argument name.

Without the code it is still not sure what "dependencies from RPATH" you are talking about. During the build, CMake adds some RPATH values for created libraries and executables. On installation (cmake --install) all these settings are cleared. If you want to know how RPATH works in CMake, you could read e.g. that article.

@Tsyvarev thank you for the link. I actually have read this and other articles prior to posting the question.
In any case, I think I understand the source of this behavior and you are right, it is not CMake. These RPATH machinations are performed by Nix on behalf of the linker (https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/bintools-wrapper/ld-wrapper.sh). There is even a comment in that script that Nix will only add paths under /nix/store because that seems the valid approach. And, I quote, "If not, we're screwed."
